# How to create 2^20 possibilities animation with Adobe Animate

Tags: animation, adobe, adobe-animate

i am new to adobe animate. I want to share with you something that worries me. I need to design an animation with 2 ^ 20 possibilities. but it seems impossible for me to create all the possibilities one by one.
I want to pack an animation that I created with adobe animate and produce it instantly according to the data from the mobile application. how can I do that. I will be very happy if you can help.
Thank you in advance, I wish you good work.

Edit:
Let me briefly describe the applications as follows: I have a competition application written in Xamarin.Forms. Only two people can race at the same time. I want to integrate a animation in this competation. The animation content will be as follows: There will be a balance board. If the 1st competitor knows the question, the side of the 2nd competitor will bow. And if the 2st competitor knows the question, the side of the 1nd competitor will bow. The contest will be deemed finished when the balance board hits the ground. The decisive data that will create the animation here will come from the correct answer to these questions. What should i do according to such a fiction? I will be happy if you could help me.

Comment: Just FYI, 2^20 is over 1 million. It is not really possible to create this amount of variants. However. If you design a picture with 20 distinct elements that can have "idle" and "active" animation variants, you can roll randomly which ones go into "active" loop and which ones go into "idle" loops, so the total amount of different combinations will be 2^20.

Comment: Hi @Organis, First of all thank you for your return.I updated my question content in detail. Can you please review?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, sorry.